# How do you get a reference to the enclosing class from an anonymous inner class in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm currently creating an explicit reference to this in the outer class so that I have a name to refer to in the anonymous inner class.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I just found this recently. Use `OuterClassName.this`.

```
class Outer {
    void foo() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Outer.this.bar();
            }
        }.start();
    }
    void bar() {
        System.out.println("BAR!");
    }
}
```

**Updated** If you just want the object itself (instead of invoking members), then `Outer.this` is the way to go.

Comment: THANK YOU! This has been bugging me for too long.  Glad the answer was a quick google search away.

Answer (score 19):

Use `EnclosingClass.this`

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Outer.class to get the class of the outer class object (which will return the same Class object as Outer.this.getClass() but is more efficient)

If you want to access statics in the enclosing class, you can use Outer.name where name is  the static field or method.