# Access a class object from its inner class

Tags: java, class, inheritance

This method is inside JFrame object, how can I pass that JFrame object as an argument to the method in its inner class??
My code is: 
The comment explains what I am interested to do:

```
public void runTime(){        
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                count++;                
                text.setText(new Integer(count).toString());
                while (count==2012){
                    //I want to pass the frame that holds this rather than null, how it is possible?
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HelloEnd", "End of World", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon("explode.jpg"));
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        tr = new Timer(1000,action);
        tr.start();
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a reference to the enclosing class from an anonymous inner class in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201/how-do-you-get-a-reference-to-the-enclosing-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class-i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully, this question wasn't [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201/how-do-you-get-a-reference-to-the-enclosing-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class-i). Anyway, try

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JFrame.this, "HelloEnd", "End of World", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon("explode.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OuterClassName.this`.

Comment: Actually, I have fell in this problem before. The context of the problem was same, I had to access the reference to enclosing class from the inner class. Thank you for you answer. It's great, solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, if your method is not static, you can use `this` and `super` keywords. Here's some [tutorial](http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/This-and-Super/). E.g.:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "HelloEnd", "End of World", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon("explode.jpg"));
```

Comment: If I use the this keyword, then this represents the action object in my code (from ActionListener class), but I want to make the parent component from outerclass.