# How does Java 8' new default interface model works (incl. diamond, multiple inheritance, and precedence)?

Tags: java, java-8

How does this new interface model works and what is about

- the diamond problem that might arise out of this
- multiple inheritance character of this implementation
- and the precedence with which the interface implementations are used
  ?

Comment: I have the impression that you could answer most of your own questions just by trying it.

Comment: That's right :) Actually I could not find the answer how the diamond problem was handled. So I've tried it myself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a detailed explanation for [Java 8' new interface model & the diamond problem of multiple inheritance](http://blog.loxal.net/2013/05/java-8-default-interface.html).

> As you might see in this examples, starting with **JDK 8**, Java
>   has introduced a kind of **multiple inheritance** as both, the
>   ***class*** and its ***interface*** might contain an
>   ***implementation*** of the same method (same name
>   & signature). To address the diamond
>   problem there is a precedence in which order an
>   implementation is used: only if the **class implements all** default / optional methods of its
>   interfaces, the code can be compiled and the implementations of this
>   class are used. **Otherwise** the compiler tries to patch the
>   missing implementation(s) with *interface's default
>   implementation*. And if there are multiple default implementations
>   of a method, then the diamond
>   problem occurs and the compiler rejects the compilation. 
>  Java 8' new interfaces model is the result of
>   approaching **backwards compatibility**, i. e. to keep
>   existing code that was written against pre Java 8 interfaces
>   compilable.

Comment: Is this really correct? Looking at [the link](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-about-the-diamond-problem/) from @ruda's answer: The diamond problem does _not_ occur if there are multiple default implementations at different levels in the interface hierarchy. Only if there are multiple default implementations at the same level. That is, only if `B` and `C` implement the method. This is not clear from this answer.

Answer (score 65):

There is a perfect explanation at [Java Lambda FAQ](http://www.lambdafaq.org/).
Here is a citation from [What about the diamond problem?](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-about-the-diamond-problem/) article there:

```
interface A {
    default void m() { ... }        
}
interface B extends A {}
interface C extends A {}
class D implements B, C {}
```

> In the initial case (the code above), the implementation of **m** inherited by **D** is unambiguously that defined by **A** — there is no other possibility. If the situation is changed so that **B** now also declares a default implementation of **m**, that becomes the implementation that **D** inherits by the “most specific implementation” rule. But if both **B** and **C** provide default implementations, then they conflict, and **D** must either use the syntax **X.super.m(...)** to explicitly choose one of them, or else redeclare the method itself, overriding all supertype declarations.

Be sure to check out previous article on rules of resolving conflicting method declarations and other articles on Java Lambda project — they are quite good.

Comment: that sounds like chaos :(  precedence?

Comment: The links are comprehensive - this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: is there any way of asking the compiler to error out rather than using the “most specific implementation” rule?

Comment: why `default` keyword after parameters?

Comment: The lambdafaq website seems to be down, here is the preserved website from the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20190906201214/http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-about-the-diamond-problem/