# no enclosing instance of the type Polylinje is accessible in scope

Tags: java

First of all, sorry for the Swedish in my code. It's a school assignment and they are written in Swedish... I hope the code is understandable.

I get this error on three lines in my code and have no idea why.

```
no enclosing instance of the type Polylinje is accessible in scope
```

My code is:

```
public class PolylinjeIterator { 
    private int aktuell = -1; 

    public PolylinjeIterator (){ 
        if (Polylinje.this.horn.length > 0) // ERROR HERE!
            aktuell = 0; 
    } 

    public boolean finnsHorn (){ 
        return aktuell != -1; 
    } 

    public Punkt horn () 
            throws java.util.NoSuchElementException{ 
        if (!this.finnsHorn ()) 
            throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException ( 
                    "slut av iterationen"); 

        Punkt horn = Polylinje.this.horn[aktuell]; // ERROR HERE!

        return horn; 
            } 

    public void gaFram (){ 
        if (aktuell >= 0 && 
                aktuell < Polylinje.this.horn.length - 1) // ERROR HERE!
            aktuell++; 
        else 
            aktuell = -1; 
    }
}
```

the code inside Polylinje.java looks like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class Polylinje {

// Instansvariabler

// En tom Polylinje
private Punkt[] horn;

// Polylinjens färg
private String farg = "svart";

// Polylinjens bredd
private int bredd = 1;



// Konstruktorer

// Polylinje skapar en Polylinje utan hörn
public Polylinje () {
    this.horn = new Punkt[0];
}

// Polylinje skapar en Polylinje med argument
public Polylinje (Punkt[] horn, String farg, int bredd)
{
    this.horn = new Punkt[horn.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < horn.length; i++)
        this.horn[i] = new Punkt (horn[i]);

    this.farg = farg;
    this.bredd = bredd;
}
public Polylinje (Punkt[] horn)
{
    this.horn = new Punkt[horn.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < horn.length; i++)
        this.horn[i] = new Punkt (horn[i]);
}



// Konvertorer

//
public String toString () {
    String s = "";
    s = "{"+Arrays.toString(horn)+", "+farg+", "+bredd+"}";
    return s;
}



// Inspektorer

// getHorn returnerar hörnen i form av Punkt-array.
public Punkt[] getHorn () {return horn;}

// getFarg returnerar färgen i form av en String.
public String getFarg () {return farg;}

// getBredd returnerar bredden i form av en integer.
public int getBredd () {return bredd;}



// Mutatorer

// setFarg låter dig ange färgen på en Polylinje.
public void setFarg (String farg) {this.farg = farg;}

// setBredd låter dig ange bredden på en Polylinje.
public void setBredd (int bredd) {this.bredd = bredd;}

// langd beräknar längden på en Polylinje.
public double langd () {

    double langd = 0;
    double d = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < (horn.length-1); i++){
        d = horn[i].avstand (horn[i+1]);
        langd += d;
    }

    return langd;
}

// laggTill lägger till en linje i slutet av Polylinjen
public void laggTill (Punkt horn) {
    Punkt[] h = new Punkt[this.horn.length + 1];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < this.horn.length; i++)
        h[i] = this.horn[i];
    h[i] = new Punkt (horn);
    this.horn = h;
}

// laggTillFramfor lägger till en linje framför en vald linje
public void laggTillFramfor (Punkt horn, String hornNamn)
{
    int pos = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < this.horn.length; i++){
      if(this.horn[i].namn == hornNamn){
         pos = i;
         break;
      }
    }

    Punkt[] h = new Punkt[this.horn.length + 1];

    for (int j = 0; j < pos; j++)
        h[j] = this.horn[j];


    for (int k = pos+1; k < h.length; k++)
        h[k] = this.horn[k-1];

    h[pos] = new Punkt (horn);

    this.horn = h;
}

//
public void taBort (String hornNamn) {}
}
```

Comment: Side note: brace-less if statements are the work of the devil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you use the phrase `Foo.this` to refer to the enclosing type from within an anonymous class. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201/how-do-you-get-a-reference-to-the-enclosing-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class) for more details.

You are not in this situation.

Based on your latest question edit, you need to just call the getters. E.g.:

```
if (Polylinje.this.horn.length > 0) // ERROR HERE!
```

should become:

```
if (polylinje.getHorn().length > 0)
```

Which will work if you have a field in your class called `polylinje` that you insert during your constructor, for instance:

```
public class PolylinjeIterator { 
    private int aktuell = -1; 
    private final Polylinje polylinje;

    public PolylinjeIterator (Polylinje polylinje){ 
        this.polylinje = polylinje;
        if (polylinje.getHorn().length > 0) 
            aktuell = 0; 
    }
```

Comment: this seemed to work, but gave some "recommendations" (the yellow lightbulbs in eclipse) in Polylinje.java instead. altough everything seems to work, so i hope this is correct :)

Comment: @user3165913 Out of interest, what are the recommendations?

Comment: nope, when i did this i ruined the code in some other places :/
the recommendetions said "the static field Polylinje.horn should be accesed in a static way"

Comment: @user3165913 You may want to post the contents of `Polylinje` into your question so that our guesswork goes away.

Comment: what do you mean with "Which will work if you have a field in your class called `polylinje` that you insert during your constructor."?

Comment: @user3165913 Well, that is what my code example at the end shows you.

Comment: i've added the code example at the end to my code, and then i get a new error on the exact same rows. "cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getHorn() from the type Polylinje"
but i cannot make getHorn static, the rest of the code will fail then.

Comment: @user3165913 You must have made a mistake. You must have typed `Polylinje.getHorn()` (note the capital 'P') at some point when I've suggested you should use `polylinje.getHorn()`. It sounds like you need to do some research to understand the difference between instance and static methods in Java. (Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/i-want-to-know-the-difference-between-static-method-and-non-static-method) for example).

Comment: ooooh! ok! :D i thught it was an spelling error you made.. but it seems to work now! thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to an instance of `Polylinje` inside `PolylinjeIterator` you will need to pass an instance of `PolylinjeIterator` to the constructor :

```
  public PolylinjeIterator (Polylinje polylinjeInstance){ 
        if (polylinjeInstance.horn().length > 0) // Assuming Punkt has a length member and horn is a method in Polylinje 
            aktuell = 0; 
    }
```

If you want to use the `Polylinje` in different places in your `PolylinjeIterator` class create a class member and assign the given instance to this member in the constructor. Then use the member in your `PolylinjeIterator` class.

Using `Polylinje.this` is meaningless since `Classes` do not have their own member as an instance. The instance is what you create as a concrete entity of your class so whenever you refer to `this` the class name is not needed

Comment: Also `Polylinje.this.horn.length > 0` won't compile. `horn()` is a method, but used as a `field`.

Comment: thanks! but now i got a new error on the exact same rows.
"horn cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Comment: You seem to have missed the fact that surrounding class is called `PolylinjeIterator` not `Polylinje`.

Comment: yep I did... will fix it

Answer (score 0):

The espression `Polylinje.this.horn` in your code is not valid. If you need to access a `horn` attribute in an instance of class `Polylinje` you need to make this instance accessible to class `PolylinjeIterator`, possibly by giving it an attribute of class `Polylinje` and initializing it in `PolylinjeIterator`'s constructor.

You also appear to use the `horn` identifier in three different ways: as a method of class `PolylinjeIterator`, as a local variable in this method and possibly as an attribute of class `Polylinje`; this is likely one source of confusion you should try to remove.

Answer (score 0):

`Polylinje.this` means that you are accessing 'this' instance in `Polylinje` class and/or  inside an inner class of `Polylinje`, this is useful when you use inside a non-static inner class (member class)/anonymous inner class of `Polylinje`. A solution is to create an instance of `Polylinje` in `PolylinjeIterator` and access `horn` through an accessor or do the required operation in `Polylinje`, or maybe declare `horn` in  `PolylinjeIterator`.