# How does finish() work in OnClick event?

Tags: java, android, oop, onclicklistener, inner-classes

I have an `Activity` with one button to quit the `Activity`.

Through the `layout.xml` I have to set the `OnClick` event to `cmd_exit` and a call to 'this.finish()' works fine

```
public void cmd_exit(View editLayout){
    this.finish();
}
```

, but when I add a `OnClickListener` instead

```
cmd_exit = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.cmd_ExitApp);
cmd_exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    finish();
    }
});
```

`this.finish()` gives error. It has to be only `finish()`.

I understand that `finish()` lives in the `Activity` class so my question is how is it working in the second snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you've created an `OnClickListener` as an anonymous class, the `this` keyword refers to that listener instance rather than the enclosing class. You could use `YourActivityClassName.this` instead. You could also just omit the `this`, and since `OnClickListener` doesn't have a `finish()` method so the `Activity` one will be used.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case `this` refers to the `Activity` instance. In the second case you have an [anonymous](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) [inner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) class instantiated with `new View.OnClickListener()` whose `this` refers to the instance of the class. Each anonymous inner class has an implicit reference to the outer class it's been instantiated in. That reference is implicitly used when calling `finish()`, i.e. `OuterClassName.this.finish()`.

> How is it working in the second snippet?

The compiler is responsible for passing a reference to the outer class instance into the inner class. It modifies each of the inner class' constructors by adding the reference to the outer class instance as a constructor parameter.

---

<sub>Reference: [Core Java Volume I - Fundamentals, 9th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137081898), Chapter 6.4: Inner Classes, page 309</sub>

---

As [@Gabe Sechan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1631193/gabe-sechan) pointed out, in order to refer to the outer class within the anonymous inner class use `OuterClassName.this`. Reference: [How do you get a reference to the enclosing class from an anonymous inner class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201/how-do-you-get-a-reference-to-the-enclosing-class-from-an-anonymous-inner-class).

Comment: And for the OP-  if you do need to use the parent's this for some reason, you use MyParentClassName.this